# Identify what column has the biggest date value and display it as a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want know what column of a table is the bigger data.

I tried use case but my problem is when a column is null, in this situation the case condition is passed.

My code :
**(EDIT)**

```
CASE WHEN data 1 >= data 2 AND data 1 >= data 3 AND
          data 1 >= data 4 THEN 'data 1'
     WHEN data 2 >= data 1 AND data 3 >= data 2 AND
          data 2 >= data 4 THEN 'data 2'
     WHEN data 3 > data 2 AND data 3 > data 1 AND
          data 3 > data 4 THEN 'data 3'
     WHEN data 4 > data 2 AND data 4 > data 1 AND
          data 4 > data 3 THEN 'data 4'
     END AS Bigger_Col_Is?
```

expected results:

```
  data 1  |  data 2  |  data 3  |  data 4  |Bigger_Col_Is?| Others Columns  
2021-01-31|   null   |2022-01-31|2022-04-20|    data 4    | others info  
2021-04-15|   null   |2022-01-31|   null   |    data 1    | others info
```

(OBS: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: Please define what "bigger data" means here.

Comment: please add your code here.

Comment: I suspect your question is really something like: how to find the greatest value (date value) from n columns and display it as a new column.

Comment: What are the datatypes of your columns?

Comment: @EduardUta exactly!

Comment: @DaleK Is datetype

Comment: What do you want it to do when a column is null? `Coalesce` will probably solve it.

Comment: @DaleK I think  it will don't work cause I want just ignore the null column and know the name of  column with the biggest date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cross apply

```
select data1, data2, data3, data4, t.n maxname
from mytable
cross apply (
    select top(1) n 
    from (
        values
          (data1,'data1'), (data2,'data2'), (data3,'data3'), (data4,'data4')
    ) t(d,n)
    order by d desc
) t
```

[db<>fidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4347719f0b88e410515a71a5aad19707)

Comment: I tnink the OP wants the name of the column, not it's value.

Comment: @Serg I get "data 1" don't exist, maybe cause the columns 'data in my query come from joins with other tables

Comment: @JoãoGaldino  yes, you should rename columns in the answer after the names in your real data.

Comment: @Serg I made that

Comment: Runs ok for me, see the fiddle